# Google Glass: voice command in activity

Tags: android, voice, google-glass, google-gdk

I am trying to figure out how to make a voice command possible in an activity itself *after* the Glassware has already started. For example, after you take a picture you can use the `OK, Glass` `share with` commands.

I want the voice commands to be possible in a certain activity after launching the Glassware.

I've checked the documentation on Google, but couldn't find one that relates to what I need.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like it would be covered by contextual voice commands. This isn't supported yet, but you may want to follow [issue 273](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273) on our issue tracker so you can get updates as the GDK evolves.

Comment: Doh! Thanks for the info. Any clue as to if this will be supported anytime soon?

Answer (score 0):

With XE19 contextual voice command is available, you need to add this line :

```
getWindow().requestFeature(WindowUtils.FEATURE_VOICE_COMMANDS);
```

Then set up a menu to show.

Here is the documentation from Google : https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#contextual_voice_commands